# Spring Boot - Where in code can I find this Bean. Is it a Bean?

Tags: spring-boot, routes, apache-camel

Hi I'm looking at a Spring Boot application and I'm trying to understand everything that it does.  It uses Camel and I am not finding the documentation for Camel especially helpful.  Basically I might have a fundamental misunderstanding that a Camel SME would really be able to help with. The piece of code I am looking at is ...

```
public class SBJobScheduler  extends RouteBuilder {
  from("direct:alertBatch")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, SB_LOGGER, "#The Scheduler is going to start ::sbJob:: batch.# ")
        .to("spring-batch:sbJob")
        .end();
```

So I am trying to find how in the heck can I know where "alertBatch" is.  I don't see any beans by this name, but maybe I'm missing it.  I just want to know what is this value and I'm using the debugger and it doesn't tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alertBatch` is the name that uniquely identifies this endpoint. From Camel documentation:

> The direct: component provides direct, synchronous invocation of any consumers when a producer sends a message exchange. This endpoint can be used to connect existing routes in the same camel context.
>
> URI format
>
> direct:someName[?options]
>
> Where someName can be any string that uniquely identifies the endpoint.

You can read more about this component [here](http://camel.apache.org/direct.html)

Comment: Ok thanks but what’s the URI of the endpoint how can I find that out

Comment: `direct:alertBatch` is the uri of this end point. Check from where it is being called, you'll see something like `to("direct:alertBatch")`

Comment: Oh ok but is there someway to know the URI? I do see that call though thanks

Comment: Which uri? How is it being called? Or something else?

Comment: Like the path I mean the mapping - the endpoint has to have a URI in the form of protocol://host:port/uri/path

Comment: URI need not be to be in this format only. You can read more here: http://camel.apache.org/uris.html .

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create a public constant in the same class that creates the route, this way, when you need to call this route, you just refer the created constant. This way you turn your code clean, more readable and allows the call hierarchy functionality from IDEs.